# RAW TCP socket in windows with C?

Tags: c, windows, sockets, tcp, raw-sockets

I am writing a proxy in C (Windows 8.1 Environment). I did the same in Linux without any trouble but in windows things look different.
First of all, I am aware of MS Windows restrictions for sending RAW TCP Data and read this post. I also found WinPcap as a potential solution. The difference is I need to add Ethernet frame (DstMac, SrcMac, and Protocol Type) and ran the following codes:

```
if ((fp = pcap_open_live(d->name,       // name of the device
    65536,          // portion of the packet to capture. It doesn't matter in this case 
    1,              // promiscuous mode (nonzero means promiscuous)
    1000,           // read timeout
    errbuf          // error buffer
    )) == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "\nUnable to open the adapter. %s is not supported by WinPcap\n", d->name);
}
```

then I created a packet:

```
u_char * data;
data = (u_char *)malloc(sizeof(u_char)*(ip_size+14));
memcpy((void*)data, (void*)dmac, 6);
memcpy((void*)(data + 6), (void*)smac, 6);
USHORT TmpType = 8;
memcpy((void*)(data + 12), (void*)&TmpType, 2);
    memcpy(data+14, iphdr, ip_size); //iphdr is the full packet -(minus) ethernet header 
    //ip_size is the sizeof(iphdr)

pcap_sendpacket(fp, data, ip_size+14); //14: size of ethernet header
free(data);
```

In my test the first iphdr is a TCP Syn packet. When I send it to the network, I can capture it in Wireshark. However, the remote server does not respond to this packet and I got [TCP Out-of-Ordfer] messages and then a few RST packet and nothing happens.
my questions are:
1- Is winpcap the only feasible solution in windows with C?
2- If no, could you please provide any example/resource for developing RAW TCP sockets in C?
3- If yes, what causes the server does not response my manually crafted TCP Syn.

PS: I use the same code for creating TCP SYN in linux and it works perfectly. So, I have no doubt the tcphdr contain the IP header, TCP header and payload with correct checksums in both IP, and TCP headers.

Comment: In the context of sockets, 'raw' and 'TCP' are mutually exclusive.

Comment: what error message do you get? you don't seem to check the return code from sendpacket.  pcap_geterr would give you more info. also you remove all the type casts, there is no reason to cast to void* or cast return value from malloc in C

Comment: is the remote server the same server you used when tried with a linux client? if not it can be a protection scheme of the OS (or something listening)